# Find appropriate function to satisfy inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Is it possible to find a differentiable $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
xf(x) \geq L \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

for an arbitrary constant $L>0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. See what happens for $x = 0$.

At every other point $f(x) = L/x$ would work.

Comment: exactly thats my problem... Can I find $f$ such that it "sucks" this zero for example with $0*1/0$ yielding a strictly positive number and $f$ be differentiable?

Comment: No, $0y = 0$, there is nothing you can do about it.